# React - useImperativeHandle exposed properties are overlapped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am creating a component "UsernameInput", that renders my custom "TextInput" component:

```
const UsernameInput = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      ...
    },
    ref
  ) => {
     ...
     
     return <TextInput ref={ref} />
  });
```

My TextInput component exposes some functionality to its parents:

```
const TextInput = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      ...
    },
    ref
  ) => {
      ...

      useImperativeHandle(
        ref,
        () => ({
          getText: () => text,
          setText,
          focus,
          blur,
      }),
      [text]
    );

    ...
  });
```

Now... in my UsernameInput component, I want to expose other functionalities too...

```
const UsernameInput = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      ...
    },
    ref
  ) => {
     ...

     useImperativeHandle(
       ref,
       () => ({
         getUsernameInformation: () => usernameInformation,
       }),
       [usernameInformation]
     );

     return <TextInput ref={ref} />
  });
```

The main problem I am experiencing is that, if I do the following:

```
const usernameInputRef = useRef(null);

const handleOnSubmit = () => {
    usernameInputRef.current.blur()
}

return (
   <UsernameInput ref={usernameInputRef} ...
);
```

The code throws me an exception ".blur() is undefined".

It seems that, because of having two `useImperativeHandle`, the exposed functionalities are overlapped.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to create a new `ref` in `UsernameInput` and use it to do the manipulation on `TextInput` within `UsernameInput` without passing the same `ref`.

Comment: nice, it works!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Amila Senadheera comment:

```
   const textInputRef = useRef(null);
    
   ...

   useImperativeHandle(
      ref,
      () => ({
        getUsernameInformation: () => usernameInformation,
        ...textInputRef.current,
      }),
      [usernameInformation]
    );

    ...

    return <TextInput ref={textInputRef} ... />
```